# Why should we use GeometryReader on background while using key preferences?And not geometry reader on the whole element?I

Tags: swiftui

Why should we use GeometryReader on background while using key preferences?And not geometry reader on the whole element?In all tutorials we should add background or overlay, why?

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .padding()
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        Color.yellow
                            .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size)
                    }
                )
            
            Spacer().frame(height: 40)
            
            Text("w: \(Int(mySize.width)) h: \(Int(mySize.height))")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.green)
        }.onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self) { newSize in
            print("The new child size is: \(newSize)")
            mySize = newSize
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? show us your code.

Comment: `GeometryReader`always uses all available space. So if you use it around your text view, it would take more or less the whole screen and put your text view in the center of it, and then return the proxy data for the enlarged frame – try it and see what happens. Usually that is not what you want. So If you want the "natural" size of your text view, apply the GeometryReader on its background (or overlay), and you get the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

Because GeometryReader is a greedy View type, it would occupy all available space, there for we should control it with background or overlay to be limited to the size of view you are about to read the proxy of it.